# Android: Canvas drawBitmap?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a 200x200px bitmap. I want to draw the top left 50x50px corner of my bitmap, on my canvas at coordinates 100,100 with a width and height of 50px, by using:

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

This is what I've tried:

```
drawBitmap(myBitmap, new Rect(0,0,50,50), new Rect(100,100,150,150) , null);
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

From developer.android.com:

**Parameters**

- **bitmap**    The bitmap to be drawn
- **src**   May be null. The subset of the bitmap to be drawn
- **dst**   The rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into
- **paint** May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap

What is missing in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the result you got from this code?

Comment: The result is a part of the image, but resized and not from the part I wanted

Comment: Is the code I wrote correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your rectangles. This is because, as described in the documentation, the first rectangle is the subset of the bitmap you want to draw, the second is the scaling/translating so basically the size of the destination draw (50x50)

So it should look like this:

```
drawBitmap(myBitmap, new Rect(100,100,150,150), new Rect(0,0,50,50) , null);
```

Comment: I'm really not understanding. The person asking the question wants the top left corner to be drawn at 100 , 100 , 150 , 150 why would switching the rects in your comment above work?@fr4gus